# Is it safe and fine if we add .Net Core packages inside asp.net projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am working on developing a remote event receiver for a SharePoint online site, and the remote event receiver is mainly an Asp.NET Web service project.. but to be able to integrate it with Azure Key vault, I need to add those packages inside my visual studio project:-

```
Install-Package Azure.Core
Install-Package Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
Install-Package Azure.Identity
```

so is it fine if we reference the `Azure.Core` inside asp.net web application project? i tired this and the project worked well.. but might i get into troubles? or this is supported operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a package name ends in ".Core" doesn't mean the package is *for* .NET Core. A package name might end in .Core and it may have no support for running on .NET Core at all. Packages that end in .Core are often the "base" package that other packages may refer to. In this case, Azure.Core is a package that many other Azure related packages depend on, so it is "core" to those package.

If you want to know whether a particular package supports .NET Framework or .NET Core or whatever, then go to the NuGet.org page for the particular package. From there, you'll see a link on the right to "Open in FuGet Package Explorer". That will take you to the FuGet page for the package, which clearly shows which frameworks are supported. I've gone ahead and retrieved the links to those pages for you:

- [Azure.Core/1.13.0](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Azure.Core/1.13.0)
- [Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/4.2.0-beta.4](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/4.2.0-beta.4)
- [Azure.Identity/1.4.0-beta.5](https://www.fuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/1.4.0-beta.5)

[image: Screenshot of Fuget.org illustrating a package that supports multiple frameworks]

In this case, all of these packages support netstandard2.0, [which means they can be used by .NET Framework 4.6.1 and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

It's actually very uncommon to see a package that *only* supports .NET Core. The usual practice with modern class libraries is to target some version of .NET Standard, unless there is a specific reason to depend directly on .NET Core.

Comment: ok thanks for the detailed info.. so at the end since my project is working after installing those packages then i should be fine.. is this correct?

Comment: @johnGu Yes....did you not get that from my answer? Is there something I need to clarify?